# Docker service discovery using DNS rather than service registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, microservices, service-discovery

I'm running an application with a multitude of back end services each running within a container. After sifting through various articles, I've reached a state of dilemma as to why do we even employ service registry for service discovery even though our Docker is kind enough to provide us a built in service discovery system?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess it would depend on the scale of your deployment.

Docker is alone sufficient for deployments in a single VM (and docker network) I suppose but what it you want to scale across VMs, Physical Hosts and Datacenters?

Service Discovery would then make more sense and also they give you a totally different level of control compared to relying on the basic implementation that docker provides itself.

So, depending on your deployment it will either be an overkill or a life saver.

Comment: Hi Pramodh, I'll be currently using Kubernetes for cluster management and I think Kubernetes has inbuilt DNS server for service discovery. In that regard, does it become necessary to deploy a service registry, as because Kubernetes would already workout all the nitty grity for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yup. `kube-dns` should be sufficient for most solutions (as long as everything is inside the cluster). But if you already have existing services (and/or service discovery with something like consul), then you might have to rethink your strategy to for services to work both inside and outside the cluster.
But if its a fresh kubernetes installation, go for it! :)
Also, do check out service meshes, like [Istio](https://istio.io), based on cluster size, it may come in handy.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the heads up. This will really help in architecture the cluster.